# How to downcast numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, types, casting, numpy-ndarray

Background: In my program, numpy.ndarrays are used to store different things (fields, materials, geometries, parameters, etc.). Often one thing is computed from another and the result is passed to the next function. If somewhere in the pipeline I forget a step, any further computations become meaningless, so I want to use a more strict type checking to avoid mistakes.

I introduced a couple of new types, all of which are essentially just new names for `ndarray`:

```py
class Field(np.ndarray):
  pass

class Geometry(np.ndarray):
  pass
```

Now I can conveniently us `isinstance` to check if the correct type is passed to a function.

However I have trouble creating these objects. Usually they should be the result of some numpy operations, so at the end of a function, I would like to cast a `np.ndarray` to a `Field` object. Just writing `Field(v)` however invokes the `nparray` constructor which fails as `v` is interpreted as shape rather than as data. Besides, I do not want to create a new object, I don't want to copy anything I just want to change the type. Usually, this would be a bad idea, but in my case I know, that a `Field` is nothing than a `ndarray` with a different name, so it should work.

So what is the best way of explicitly casting a `ndarray` to a `Field` object?

Bonus question: If I `np.save` and `np.load` my subclass object, the type is not preserved and I only read a `ndarray`. Is there a recommended (efficient) alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the numpy documentation already describes this specific case:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html